# How to execute a script that asks password with snmp

Tags: linux, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

i have been trying to execute a script with snmpget that has this code :

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -S ufw disable
```

But when i use SNMPGET to execute this script , terminal asks password as an output :

NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutLine."script1".1 = STRING: [sudo] password for Debian-snmp:

So my question is that how can i fix the issue legally ?

Comment: You could either add the command / user to the [sudoers](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) if `sudo` is asking for the password. Or look into [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) to automatically enter the password. However, you'd probably have to hard-code the password in your script with this approach, which may or may not be a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the sudo password, and any other input for your script, using `nsExtendInput`.

Comment: I really dont know how to use nsExtendInput .Is there any source to teach me  how to use nsExtendInput ? And do i need to set my password inside nsExtendInput ? Thanks

Comment: It's part of `NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB`, so it should be similar to whatever you are already doing to execute the script

Comment: So i use this `snmpget -v3 -a MD5 -A AuthPassword -X CryptoPassword -l authNoPriv -u privUser localhost 'NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutLine."script1".1' ` , i guess you want me to change nsExtendOutline with nsExtendInput , but how can i add my password into that .

Comment: You should read the description of `nsExtendInput` in `NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB` to understand how to use it. Here's a link to an online copy if you need it: http://www.circitor.fr/Mibs/Mib/N/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.mib

Comment: hello sir , when i try to set something to nsExtendInput with this code `sudo snmpset -v3 -a MD5 -A AuthPassword -X CryptoPassword -l authNoPriv -u privUser  localhost   'NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendInput."script1"' s "121232131"` , i get this error rror in packet.

Reason: noAccess

Failed object: NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendInput."script1"   i wasnt able to figure this error out . And i want able to figure out how to use  nsExtendInput  by MIB text. Is there any example that you can show ? Thanks